# How to let computers at the same physical location, but on two separate networks, talk to each other?

Tags: networking, router, routing, lan

I have two networks at my house:

Network A:

- Router A with Cable Internet and Wi-Fi A
- DHCP 192.168.1.x
- 5 computers
- 3 smart TVs
- bunch of random devices

Network B:

- Router B with Cable Internet and Wi-Fi B
- DCHP 192.168.2.x
- 2 computers
- 5 tablets
- bunch of other random devices

I want all of the devices on Network A to use Router A for internet access. I want all of the devices on Network B to user Router B for internet access. I want all of the devices on Network A to be able to talk to everything on Network B (and vice versa).

I would prefer to do this with my existing consumer-grade routers which are TP-Link AX3000. Really don't want to set up a Linux server or anything like that.

I'm not worried about security or restrictions between networks. Just need respective networks to use their own internet, but be able to talk to each other as if they were on the same network.

Comment: I have two separate internet services. One service provides for devices on Network A, one for Network B. Devices must use their respective connection for internet access.

Comment: The simple and consumer-grade solution is to use routers as routers instead of glorified internet access devices. Which means you connect them up, e.g. via LAN, and set routes on each. Done. Unfortunately, consumer-grader home-router firmware usually makes that difficult or impossible to do. So if the firmware on your routers can't do that, the next not-so-consumer-friendly step is to install custom firmware like OpenWRT which can do it. Which may or may not be possible for your routers.

Comment: @John VPN is not the way to go, it would route all traffic between networks over the internet making things slow. The real way is as dirkt mentions, bridging the routers to a network with 2 WAN ports and have VLAN's setup to route traffic to different internet points.

Comment: Another option is to have all computers connected to a router via LAN but no internet access, and each computer also connected to separate routers via WIFI and only have internet on here. Ensure the IP range for WIFI is different for LAN, set gateway addres for the wifi and it should work

Comment: if you have a router for one network and a router for another network, very isolated.. how about a third router that each of those routers connects to?

Answer (score 1):

Your AX3000 routers don't fully support creating multiple local LAN's.
(They can do VLANs, but don't seem to be able to assign an IP address to their own interfaces in those VLANs.)

So this won't happen unless you have another device to act as intermediary between the LAN's.
They do support static routes though, which makes the interconnect relatively simple.

You need a 3rd router with 2 LAN interfaces. One with an IP-address in LAN A and one in LAN B.
Then set on each TP-Link AX3000 a static route to the OTHER LAN via the corresponding LAN interface of the 3rd router.

E.g. Extra router has 192.168.1.254 in LAN A and 192.168.2.254 in LAN B
On router A you would set a route for 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 pointing to 192.168.1.254
And on B you would set a route for 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 to 192.168.2.254

Comment: This sounds straight forward, thank you. I'll give it a try.